# spark-shell declining offers from mesos master

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, mesosphere

I have been trying to learn spark on mesos, but the spark-shell just keeps on ignoring the offers. Here is my setup:

All the components are in the same subnet

- 1 mesos master  on EC2 instance (t2.micro)

  command: `mesos-master  --work_dir=/tmp/abc --hostname=<public IP>`
- 2 mesos agents (each with 4 cores, 16 GB ram and 30 GB disk space)

  command: `mesos-slave --master="<private IP of master>:5050" --hostname="<private IP of slave>" --work_dir=/tmp/abc`
- 1 spark-shell (client) on ec2 instance (t2.micro)
  I have set the following environment variables on this instance before launching the spark-shell

  ```
  export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libmesos.so
  export SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI=local://home/ubuntu/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
  ```

  and then I launch the the spark-shell as follows

  ```
  ./bin/spark-shell --master mesos://172.31.1.93:5050
  ```

  (private IP of the master)

  I have ensured that `spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz` is placed in
  `/home/ubuntu` on both the agents, before starting the spark shell.

Once the spark-shell is up, I run the simplest program possible

```
val f = sc.textFile ("/tmp/ok.txt");
f.count()
```

.. and I keep getting the following logs on spark-shell

```
 (0 + 0) / 2]17/05/21 15:13:34 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
17/05/21 15:13:49 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
17/05/21 15:14:04 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Master side logs: (these logs I see even before doing anything inside spark-shell and they keep coming even after I have run the above code in the spark shell)

```
I0521 15:14:12.949108 10166 master.cpp:6992] Sending 2 offers to framework 64c1ef67-9e4f-4236-bb86-80d7aaab540f-0000 (Spark shell) at scheduler-7a375e65-7a0d-4267-befa-e69937404d5f@172.31.1.203:45596
I0521 15:14:12.955731 10164 master.cpp:4731] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ 64c1ef67-9e4f-4236-bb86-80d7aaab540f-O34 ] for framework 64c1ef67-9e4f-4236-bb86-80d7aaab540f-0000 (Spark shell) at scheduler-7a375e65-7a0d-4267-befa-e69937404d5f@172.31.1.203:45596
I0521 15:14:12.956130 10167 master.cpp:4731] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ 64c1ef67-9e4f-4236-bb86-80d7aaab540f-O35 ] for framework 64c1ef67-9e4f-4236-bb86-80d7aaab540f-0000 (Spark shell) at scheduler-7a375e65-7a0d-4267-befa-e69937404d5f@172.31.1.203:45596
```

I am using Mesos 1.2.0 and spark 2.1.1 on Ubuntu 16.04. I have verified by writing a small node.js based http client and the offers from the master seem fine. What possibly is going wrong here?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/common-spark-troubleshooting)? Can you post a workers info and offers that were declined? It might be a problem related to IPs. Can you confirm that offers IP match with configuration? Offer contains the same Master IP you are using to connect?

Comment: It was basically failing to handle the executor uri beginning with "local". I changed it to "http" and it went ahead and failed with some other reason. here are the logs:  https://pastebin.ca/3815427

Comment: Ok figured out the problem. The executor inside the agent tries to bind  to the public IP which is bound to fail when running in ec2. Set the hostname argument of the mesos-agent  to the private Ip and it worked.

Comment: Cool, add it as an answer and accept. You can set `LIBPROCES_IP` to achieve similar effect.

Comment: posted the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, There were two problems here.

1. The `SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI` was `local`, so changed it to `http`. `local` I guess is for hadoop (correct me here incase).
2. After changing the URI to `local` , the netty blockmanager service that runs as a part of spark executor launched by mesos-executor (as a task, coarse mode) which is launched by Mesos Containerizer which is launched by mesos-agent, used to fail trying to bind to the public IP because I had passed the hostname as the public IP to the mesos-agent, which is bound to fail in EC2.  In fact, I was passing private IP  at first  but don't remember why I changed the hostname to public IP. Probably, to check for the sandbox logs I guess. The Mesos master was redirecting it to the mesos-agent's private IP preventing me to see the stderr logs. (I am located outside the EC2 VPC).  Note, the question above has private IP being passed to the agent, which is correct. Originally, The question above was posted  for the first problem.